# Traversing nested JSON structs

Tags: json, go, traversal

I want to traverse the nested JSON struct and get each key and value from the interface{}

http://play.golang.org/p/B-B3pejGJW

So I want from the following struct

```
    {
        "tg": {
            "A": {
                "E": 100,
                "H": 14
            },
            "B": {
                "D": 1
            },
            "C": {
                "D": 1,
                "E": 1
            },
            "D": {
                "F": 1,
                "G": 1,
                "H": 1
            },
            "E": {
                "G": 1
            }
        }
    }
```

I was able to get the following

```
a := js.Get("tg").Get("D").Get("F")
fmt.Println(*a) // {1}
```

but having trouble with type assert this to integer.

```
     invalid type assertion: (*a).(int)
```

How would would traverse this whole struct and get each integer mapped from the characters?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the code that generated the error?  There isn't much context for it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value will be marshalled into a `float64`. Plus you are not accessing `a.data` but `a` instead which is a struct which is causing the error.

```
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a)              // &main.JSON{data:1}
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(a.data)) // float64
x := int(a.data.(float64))
```